# How to detect what page user is on with php

Tags: php, detect

I need to create some `if` `else` statements depending on what page user is, I tried looking for this in php manual, but didn't find anything useful.

Basically what I want is a syntax for something like:

```
if (user is on a page index.php)

 $message = $_GET["title"];
 if $message = "hello";
 $say = "Hello";

etc ....
```

Can anyone show how this can be done?

Comment: @jprofitt it may not be a duplicate. If the URI requested is redirected in some way by the server, PHP may be processing a different file than what the URI seems to be pointing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at `_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`, `_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]`, `_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME]`, `_SERVER[PHP_SELF]`, and possibly others.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php  A full list of Server values, also you can use the __FILE__ constant as listed on that page.  SO makes it bold but there are two underscores before and after FILE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a session variable to track the user: every page is opened set a session variable to it's name so you can know what is the last opened page

Comment: This requires similar but different code on every page with a constant value for the name. Also, if the file name changes for any reason you'd have to go back in and edit it.

Comment: may be i miss understood the question, i ti the right answer if you want to know on what page of your site certain user is

Comment: I don't think sessions are necessary.

Comment: yes, you are right, should i delete the answer? (while now is not responding to the user question)

Answer (score -1):

x = str_replace('.php', '', (end(explode('/',HttpRequest::getUrl))));

Comment: HttpRequest::getUrl wil this get a full url?

Answer (score -1):

Current Url :

```
$currenturl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Curren File: `$_SERVRER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`